# rails - find with condition in rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, find, conditional-statements

I recently upgraded my rails to Rails 4.1.6.

This query used to work :

```
@user = User.find(:all, :conditions => { :name => 'batman' })
```

Now I get this error message:

```
Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>{:name=>"batman"}}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

When I check the logs I can see that rails is trying to do a completely different query :

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" IN ('all', '---
:conditions:
  :name: batman
')
```

It looks like, it's trying to get all the users with the id "all" and "{:conditions=>{:name=>"batman"}}". Please help.

UPDATE:

My real question behind that was I want to get a specific user and add to it his cars, only the cars that are blue. For example this is my query, the user id is 20.

```
@user = User.joins(:cars).find(20, :cars => {:color => "blue"})
```

But I get this error:

> Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (20, {:cars=>{:color=>"blue"}})
>   (found 41 results, but was looking for 2)

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely read this [ActiveRecord Query Interface quide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions)

`User.where(name: "batman")`

Comment: Yes there are plenty of options. Here is entire section about this problematic - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object I truly encourage you to read it through, these are the basics of ActiveRecord and it will give you good fundation

Comment: Hi Tome, yes you're right. I have updated my post. Now you can understand why I tried this query.

Comment: If you need specific user, use primary key to find it, for example with ID as your primary key: ```Client.find(ID)```.

Comment: Yes but the point here is that I want to make one query and join to that Client another table and make some conditions...

Answer (score 2):

Some others already pointed out: The query syntax changed. Try this:

```
@user = User.joins(:cars).where(:cars => { :color => "blue" }).find(20)
```

Note that this will raise an exception if that record is not found, to return an array empty instead call:

```
@user = User.joins(:cars).where(:id => 20, :cars => { :color => "blue" })
```

I suggest to read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

---

If you want to load the user even if he does not have any cars and than display only his blue cars, I would do it like this:

```
@user = User.find(20)              # returns the user
@user.cars.where(:color => 'blue') # returns the user's blue cars (or an empty array)
```

Comment: Thank you that's very close to what I'm looking for !! The only thing now is when the user doesn't have any cars I get an error message even if the user 19 actually exist "Couldn't find User with 'id'=19 [WHERE "cars"."color" = "blue"]". If the user doesn't have cars I still want to be able to get his info and just have an empty "cars": []

Comment: Thanks spickermann for your help. I tried your new query I got this error message: undefined method `valid?' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>.  "if that record is not found, to return an empty" I still want to get the user information such as email, name, ... and if no cars "cars": []

Answer (score -2):

The `find` method is deprecated in this version of Rails (see [the reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class)).
Instead, you must use the `where` method.

In your case, you should write `@user = User(:name => 'batman')` or  `@user = User(name: 'batman')`